# Sublime text user keymap not overriding default

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Lubuntu, have changed just one shortcut on sublime user keymap, but nothing that i change there takes any effect.

on default keymap, i have this

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pageup"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pagedown"], "command": "prev_view" },
```

on userkeyma, i replaced it with this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+pageup"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["alt+pagedown"], "command": "prev_view" },
```

but it takes no effect whatsoever
this is sublime text 3 build 3083

Comment: Open the Sublime console, enter `sublime.log_input(True)` followed by `sublime.log_commands(True)`; then press one of those keys. What does the console say? Also, why are you using such an old version of Sublime?

Comment: tried to update it.. went to the official website, they have listed some console commands to run in order to update. the first one of the, i suppose is meant to add a repository. i get the 404 error.

i tried a direct download, uncompressed it, but the resulting folder has a sublime text exe that just opens the version i already have. i'm noob to linux actually @OdatNurd

Comment: When you run Sublime when it's already running, it doesn't start a new copy; so probably you still had the old version running when you started the new one. Did you try the console commands I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: Yes. ctrl + page up will show "command: prev_view". alt + page up will show nothing. which is in accordance with the default keymap. @OdatNurd

Comment: The input logging tells you what keys you're pressing and command logging tells you what commands are being executed; if you don't see anything (including a key) your problem is that your window manager is using that key for something, so it blocks Sublime from even knowing it happened.

Comment: i tried to replace the shortcut i'm talking about to other keys, and nothing happens. the issue really seems to be that it keeps looking at the default keymap file instead of the user keymap file @OdatNurd

Comment: What's the full filename of the file you added your mappings to?

Comment: /home/david/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap

The default keymap is supposed to be on /home/david/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/, but that folder doesn't exist nor is hidden. When i try to create it, some weird stuff happens. This one time, sublime's background became white, now i tried doing it again, and most shortcuts (including backspace) stopped working.

Comment: The `Default` package ships with Sublime as a `sublime-package` file so it doesn't exist where you think it does (and putting it there has consequences if you're not careful, as you've noticed ;)). The bindings look OK in isolation and the path seems OK as well; no error messages in the console? Can you edit your question to show your complete User key bindings?